# Inequality of numerical radius

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I want to ask on how to prove this inequality
$$|\langle Tx,x\rangle|\leq w(T)||x||^{2}.$$ Where $w(T)=(\sup|\langle Tx,x\rangle|;||x||=1)$

Also, about the inequality, I would go with it like this
$$|\langle Tx,x\rangle |\leq ||Tx||||x||(CS)\leq ||T||||x||^{2}(Since~T~is~bounded)$$
I don't know how to obtain $w(T)$ from this.
T is a bounded linear operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be in the domain of $T$ with $x\neq 0$. Then $y = \frac{x}{\Vert x \Vert}$ has norm 1. Hence
\begin{align*}
\vert\langle Ty, y \rangle\vert \leq w(T).
\end{align*}
Now multiply the inequality with $\Vert x \Vert^2 \neq 0$. This yields
\begin{align*}
\vert \langle Tx, x\rangle\vert \leq w(T) \Vert x \Vert^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.
Can I ask one question, the first inequality follows from the fact that $|\langle Ty,y\rangle |$ is always less or equal to the sup of it, I mean, w(T) is the sup of the left hand side.
And the second line is obtained by pulling $\frac{1}{||x||}$ out from both slots , then multiplying by $||x||^{2}$ clears it

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic exactly